# Proper Database Design lookup tables or not

Tags: sql-server, database

I am creating a SQL Server database that will be used in a web api for both a web application and mobile.

I've always used lookup tables (example: Category Lookup Table) and referenced the IDs (Product Table with CategoryID)

I don't know if I'm doing this using old methods.

```
Categories (Lookup Table)
---------
CategoryID
CategoryName


SubCategories (Lookup Table)
----------
SubCategoryID
SubCategoryName
CategoryID

Products
--------
SubCategoryID
ProductName
```

.....

My question is, is this still the proper way? Or do I skip the lookup table and call out the SubCategory directly?

```
Products
------
SubCategoryName
ProductName
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The second way is 'denormalised' which is normal for a reporting database but bad for a OLTP (database actually used for entering data)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in tow ways
1.

### Categories (Lookup Table)

CategoryID
CategoryName

### SubCategories (Lookup Table)

SubCategoryID
SubCategoryName
CategoryID

### Products

ProductName
CategoryID
SubCategoryID

link both id's with foreign keys, it is normalized way

2. Answer of your question is here.
   if you want more waster way you can approach denormalized structure.

### Categories (Lookup Table)

CategoryID
CategoryName

### SubCategories (Lookup Table)

SubCategoryID
SubCategoryName
CategoryID

### Products

ProductName
Categoryname
SubCategoryname

create an insert/update trigger on Products table to make sure the Categoryname/subCategoryname are valid.Data consistency will be maintained.

You will get faster data from this approach.